# Why does the following table not compile?

Tags: tables

It would be very kind of you if you helped me fix that. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{RPNI - example}
    $ S_+ :=\{a,b,aa\} $, $ S_- :=\{\varepsilon, ab, aab\} $\\
    
    \begin{tabular}[l | c]
        $ PTA(S_+) $
        &
        a
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably `[l | c]` needs to be `{l | c }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is

```
! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.
```

as you have

```
\begin{tabular}[l | c]
```

when you intended

```
\begin{tabular}{l | c}
```

Comment: I was 18 sec faster (though just a comment)

Comment: Thank you both!

Comment: @daleif I saw after I posted, but I did take at least 18 seconds to run the thing and copy the error message:-)